# Logging SLF4J stopwatch to different files

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, monitoring, perf4j

I'm using SLF4J StopWatch in my Java SpringBoot application to log method execution times for monitoring purposes. I'm using Perf4J jar to get statistics and graphical outputs. All my StopWatch logs get appended into my Perf4J log file. However I'd like to log them in two or more different log files, because I need to analyze Controller methods and third party API calls separately. Is there any way to do this? And what are good alternatives to Perf4J for my purpose?